# Random shutdowns that look like kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic, shutdown, console

But with no sign of kernel panic in the console. The screen just turns black all of a sudden, but the backlight stays on. After up to 10 seconds, it shuts down completely. People I talked to over Apple chat were convinced it was a battery problem, but the battery drains normally, and the problem appears with or without the power cable connected. They had me reset NVRAM and SMC, still no change. I booted into a linux distro from an external drive and used it for more than 12 hours without any interruption. Although not definitive, this strongly suggests that this might be a software problem rather than an hardware problem. If so, how could I pinpoint a problem that doesn't show up in the console? I'm using `10.11.6`.

**Edit:** I should also add that this happens in irregular intervals. It can be as frequent as once in 20 minutes, or as sporadic as every 5 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into recovery mode and reinstall MacOS. That sounds like a software issue. Give that a try, if the results are still the same, then you may have a bad drive.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tomorrow. I'm just curious: is there a way to pinpoint what piece of software is causing the problem?

Comment: This process will let you know if MacOS is the culprit. Other than that if it isnt MacOS then its hardware related.

Comment: Does it matter if I do a clean install or not?

Comment: I wouldn't do that yet. Let that be a last resort. Just because you'll want to see if it lets you backup your things. If this doesnt work then yes give it a shot.

Comment: Also check to see if the hard drive is mounted in disk utility while in recovery mode. A disk that wont mount is a clear cut sign of a bad disk drive.

Comment: So I ended up doing a clean install. The hard drive showed up fine in disk utility, prior to wiping it. But anyway, the clean install didn't solve the problem at all. I installed 10.12.6, so now I can't see the entries in the console prior to reboot (apparently that's a sierra thing).

Comment: Contact Apple support. They'll investigate further. It could be a kernel problem. Ultimately they'll probably send the info to the engineering team.

Comment: Yeah I got an appointment but the earliest was 7 days away. It snowed in the south and everyone lost their minds...

Comment: Lmao true lol. Let us know what they found. It can help someone else. Do you still have the warranty?

Comment: Nope, it's a mid 2014 MBP retina. I decided in the meanwhile I can try to wipe the drive once more and this time do not install any apps and migrate any data, and see what happens. It's a long shot, but I might as well try...

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Didn't try it yet. I'm running various memory and ssd tests in linux...

Comment: So I took it to the Apple store. They did their hardware diagnostic and couldn't find anything. They said it might be a logic board problem and so they sent it off to their repair facility. If they replace anything, it's a flat rate of $475. If they find any evidence of liquid spill, it's $800. There had been a very minor liquid spill months ago, so they might see the indicators triggered and charge me $800. In that case, I'm thinking of taking to a 3rd party repairer. What do you think?

Comment: They ended up changing the logic board and ssd and charged $575 for it.

Comment: Ok, thank goodness it wasn't $800. How are things running now?

Comment: It looks okay so far. I thought maybe it was running hotter than usual, but it seems fine now.